# Is there a ootb sharepoint list control?

Tags: sharepoint

I need a control which simply outputs a list of items.  Much like the summary link control but without the links.  I thought about using the summary link control and use xsl to style the list, but the link field is required.  So this is no good.

Is there anything?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the [Content Query Web Part](http://www.datasprings.com/Resources/ArticlesInformation/AboutSharePointContentQueryWebPart.aspx) or the [Content Editor Web Part](http://www.fpweb.net/sharepoint-tutorials/ContentEditorWebPart.asp)?

Comment: The content query webpart is too much for what i'm trying achieve?  I don't really need/want a backend list to store the data.  I just need display a list of text.  Much like the SummaryLinks control but without specifying a url.

Comment: The Content Editor Web Part will let you add random HTML to the page, added link to original reply.

Comment: For my purposes The Content Editor Webpart and the HTML publishing field are very similar..